# cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon

Tags: c#, string, messagebox

I'm working on a piece of software that lets you generate your own customized `Messagebox`. My code has no errors until I try and put in the MessageBoxButtons and `MessageBoxIcon`. Then, I get Error

> 2 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' and Error  3   Argument 4: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon'. What is the issue here?

```
if (textBoxX1.Text == String.Empty)
    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a title.");
else if (richTextBoxEx1.Text == String.Empty)
    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a body.");
else
{
    string previewtype = string.Empty;
    string previewbutton = string.Empty;
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        previewtype = "MessageBoxIcon.Error";
    else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        previewtype = "MessageBoxIcon.Information";
    else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        previewtype = "MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation";
    else if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        previewtype = "MessageBoxIcon.Question";
    if (radioButton8.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = "MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore";
    else if (radioButton7.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = "MessageBoxButtons.OK";
    else if (radioButton6.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = "MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel";
    else if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = "MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel";
    else if (radioButton9.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = "MessageBoxButtons.YesNo";
    else if (radioButton10.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = "MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel";
    MessageBox.Show(textBoxX1.Text, richTextBoxEx1.Text, previewbutton, previewtype);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you're passing strings to MessageBox.Show(), where you should be passing MessageBoxButtons and MessageBoxIcon. In other words, you cannot do this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Some text", "a caption", "MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore", "MessageBoxIcon.Error");
```

But you can do this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Some text", "a caption", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Your previewtype and previewbutton variables should be defined as the actual types, not as strings:

```
MessageBoxIcon previewtype;
MessageBoxButtons previewbutton;
```

If we update your sample to use the correct data types, it looks like this:

```
if (textBoxX1.Text == String.Empty)
    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a title.");
else if (richTextBoxEx1.Text == String.Empty)
    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a body.");
else
{
    MessageBoxIcon previewtype;
    MessageBoxButtons previewbutton;
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        previewtype = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
    else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        previewtype = MessageBoxIcon.Information;
    else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        previewtype = MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation;
    else if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        previewtype = MessageBoxIcon.Question;
    if (radioButton8.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore;
    else if (radioButton7.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
    else if (radioButton6.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;
    else if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel;
    else if (radioButton9.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
    else if (radioButton10.Checked == true)
        previewbutton = MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel;
    MessageBox.Show(textBoxX1.Text, richTextBoxEx1.Text, previewbutton, previewtype);
```

Comment: So I could do something like 'MessageBoxIcon previewtype = MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation'?

Comment: Yep exactly. I just updated the answer to show what the corrected code looks like. You mostly just have to remove all the quotes. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageBox.Show(textBoxX1.Text, richTextBoxEx1.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

The 3rd and 4th arguments doesn't expect a string value. You should pass values which are of types `MessageBoxButton` and `MessageBoxIcon`

So instead of assigning a string value, you can give the required type in the if-else conditions.

```
MessageBoxButton previewbutton;
MessageBoxIcon previewtype;

 if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    previewtype = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
```

Comment: The user is supposed to choose the icon and button though.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that when you say

```
MessageBox.Show(textBoxX1.Text, richTextBoxEx1.Text, previewbutton, previewtype);
```

you are passing two strings named `previewButton` and `previewtype` as arguments to the MessageBox.Show method while the system is expecting `MessageBoxButtons` and `MessageBoxIcon` type in their place.

The [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `MessageBox.Show` method as you are using is like this

```
MessageBox.Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon)
```

but you are passing two strings - hence the error.